# metric for completely positive contractive maps

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, summation, c-star-algebras, nets

Let $A$ be separable $C^*$-algebra and $B$ a arbitrary $C^*$-algebra and $\operatorname{CPC(A,B)}:=\{f:A\to B | f\;\text{ is completely positive contractive}\}$. Let $\{a_1,a_2,,\}$ a countable dense subset in $A^1=\{a\in A:\|a\|\le 1\}$. For $f,g\in \operatorname{CPC(A,B)}$ define a metric $$d_B(f,g):=\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty 2^{-k}\|f(a_k)-g(a_k)\|.$$

Clearly $d_B(f,g)\le 2\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty 2^{-k}<\infty$ and all the metric properties are easy to prove.

My first question: For the well-definedness of $d_B$, do I have to check that the definition of $d_B$ doesn't depend on the choice of the dense subset $\{a_1,a_2,,\}$ ?  Furthermore I want to prove: for nets $(f_{\lambda})_\lambda\subseteq \operatorname{CPC(A,B)}$,   it is

$$d_B(f_{\lambda},f)\to 0 \iff \|f_\lambda (a_k)-f(a_k)\|\to 0\ \text{ for all k}\in \mathbb{N}.$$

Since this implies that for all choices of dense subsets $\{a_1,a_2,,\}$, $d_B$ induces the same topology on $\operatorname{CPC(A,B)}$. However, here I'm stuck, my second question is:  Why is $$\lim_\lambda  \sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty 2^{-k}\|f_\lambda (a_k)-f(a_k)\|=\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty \lim_\lambda 2^{-k} \|f_\lambda (a_k)-f(a_k)\|?$$

I appreciate your help

Comment: The definition depends on the dense subset. Probably different dense subsets give rise to equivalent metrics...

Comment: You are right, sorry. the second question is only improtant to know to justify that for all the other dense subsets this metric induces the same topology on CPC(A,B)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition does depend on the sequence $\{a_k\}$; even by reordering you would most likely change the metric.

Suppose that $d_B(f_\lambda,f)\to0$. Then, for any fixed $k$, 
$$
\|f_\lambda(a_k)-f(a_k)\|\leq 2^k d_B(f_\lambda,f)\to0.
$$

Conversely, suppose that $\|f_\lambda(a_k)-f(a_k)\|\to0$ for all $k$. Fix $\varepsilon>0$. Choose $m$ such that $2^{-m+1}<\varepsilon/2$. Choose $\lambda_0$ such that $$\|f_\lambda(a_k)-f(a_k)\|<\varepsilon/2,\ \ \ k=1,\ldots,m$$ for all $\lambda\geq\lambda_0$ (this can be done, since we are using finitely many $k$). Now
\begin{align}
d_B(f_\lambda,f)&=\sum_{k=1}^m2^{-k}\|f_\lambda(a_k)-f(a_k)\|+\sum_{k=m+1}^\infty2^{-k}\|f_\lambda(a_k)-f(a_k)\|\\ \ \\
&\leq\frac\varepsilon2\,\sum_{k=1}^m2^{-k}+\sum_{k=m+1}^\infty2^{-k+1}\\ \ \\
&\leq\frac\varepsilon2+2^{-m+1}\leq\frac\varepsilon2+\frac\varepsilon2=\varepsilon.
\end{align}
 In other words, if $\lambda\geq\lambda_0$, then $d_B(f_\lambda,f)<\varepsilon$.