# space of completely positive contractive liftable maps is a complete metric space

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Let $A$ be separable $C^*$-algebra and $B$ a arbitrary $C^*$-algebra and $\operatorname{CPC(A,B)}:=\{f:A\to B | f\;\text{ is completely positive contractive}\}$. Let $\{a_1,a_2,,\}$ a countable dense subset in $A^1=\{a\in A:\|a\|\le 1\}$. For $f,g\in \operatorname{CPC(A,B)}$ define a metric $$d_B(f,g):=\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty 2^{-k}\|f(a_k)-g(a_k)\|.$$
( see my question [metric for completely positive contractive maps](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1985049/metric-for-completely-positive-contractive-maps) ). I have several questions concerning the proof of theorem 2.1 in Arveson's paper notes "notes on the lifting theorem". The theorem states (I'm interested in a slightly different version for CPC-maps instead of UCP-maps, but there should be no difference in the proof):

Theorem: Let $A$ be a separable $C^*$-algebra, $B$ a arbitrary $C^*$-algebra and let $J$ be an ideal in $B$. Then the set of all liftable CPC-maps (with CPC-lifts) from $A$ to $B/J$ is $d_{B/J}-$closed in $\operatorname{CPC}(A,B/J)$.

Proof: Let $(\phi_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of liftable maps in $\operatorname{CPC}(A,B/J)$ ( i.e. for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ there exists a CPC-map $\hat{\phi_n}:A\to B$ such that $\pi\circ \hat{\phi_n}=\phi_n$, where $\pi:B\to B/J$ is the canonical quotient map) and such that $(\phi_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ converges to a map $\phi\in \operatorname{CPC}(A,B/J)$ relative to $d_{B/J}$. We have to check that $\phi$ is liftable (and the lift is cpc). Since $(\phi_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ converges to a map $\phi\in \operatorname{CPC}(A,B/J)$ relative to $d_{B/J}$, we can arrange that $d_{B/J}(\phi_n, \phi)<\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}$ for $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

We claim that there is a sequence $(\psi_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}} \subseteq \operatorname{CPC}(A,B)$ satisfying $\pi\circ \psi_n =\phi_n$ and $d_{B}(\psi_n, \psi_{n+1})<\frac{1}{2^{n}}$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

Indeed, let $\psi_1$ be any CPC-lifting of $\phi_1$. Assuming that $\psi_1,...,\psi_n$ have been defined and satisfy the stated conditions, choose any lifting $\lambda$ of $\phi_{n+1}$. We then have $d_{B/J}(\pi\circ\psi_n,\pi\circ \lambda )=d_{B/J}(\phi_{n},\phi_{n+1} )<\frac{1}{2^{n}}$. It's now possible to conclude that there is a CPC-map $\psi_{n+1}\in \operatorname{CPC}(A,B)$ satisfying $\pi\circ\psi_{n+1} = \pi\circ \lambda =\phi_{n+1}$ and $d(\psi_n, \psi_{n+1})<\frac{1}{2^{n}}$. Since $(\psi_n)$ is a cauchy-sequence in $\operatorname{CPC}(A,B)$ relative to $d_B$ and $\operatorname{CPC}(A,B)$ is $d_B$-complete, we can define a CPC-limit $\psi$ as the $d_B$-limit of $(\psi_n)$. Since $\pi\circ \psi_n=\phi_n$ and $(\psi_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ converges to $\phi$, while $\pi\circ \psi_n$ converges to $\pi\circ \psi$, $\psi$ is a lifting of $\phi$.

My questions:

1. In the induction basis, if we choose an arbitrary lifting $\psi_1$, why we can arrange that $d_{B}(\psi_n, \psi_{n+1})<\frac{1}{2^{n}}$ for $n\in\mathbb{N}$, or repsectively how to arrange that $d_{B}(\psi_n, \psi_{n+1})<\frac{1}{2^{n}}$ for $n\in\mathbb{N}$?
2. Why is $\operatorname{CPC}(A,B)$ is $d_B$-complete?

My thoughts to my second question (can you check if everything is correct?): As stated here [metric for completely positive contractive maps](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1985049/metric-for-completely-positive-contractive-maps)
for nets $(f_{\lambda})_\lambda\subseteq \operatorname{CPC(A,B)}$,   it is

$$d_B(f_{\lambda},f)\to 0 \iff \|f_\lambda (a_k)-f(a_k)\|\to 0\ \text{ for all k}\in \mathbb{N}.$$ It follows that a sequence $(\epsilon_n)\subseteq \operatorname{CPC(A,B)}$ is $d_B$-cauchy iff $(\epsilon_n(a))\subseteq B$ is a Cauchy sequence for fixed, but arbitrary $a\in A$. Since $B$ is complete, for all $a\in A$ the limit $$\|\enspace \|_B-\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \epsilon_n(a)=\epsilon(a)$$ in $B$ exists.
Thus we can define a map $\epsilon :A\to B$ which is positive. That $\epsilon$ is completely positive I would argue similar. And $\epsilon$ is contractive, since for all $a\in A$ it is $$\|\epsilon (a)\|=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\|\epsilon_n(a)\|\le \limsup\|\epsilon_n\|\|a\|\le \|a\|.$$ Is it correct?

A appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your copy of Arveson's text, you wrote "It's now possible to conclude that..." instead of the original "Lemma 1.2 implies that..." Maybe less obvious is that there is a typo in Arveson's text and it should have said "Lemma 2.2".

Lemma 2.2 is the exact statement that you are skipping in your text. Given $\psi_1,\lambda:A\to B$, and $\varepsilon>0$, there exists ucp $\psi_2:A\to B$ such that $$d(\psi_1,\psi_2)\leq d(\pi\circ\psi_1,\pi\circ\lambda)+\varepsilon.$$

Arveson claims that the details for the estimate in the proof of this lemma are in his 1977 Duke paper. I may have a paper copy of that paper somewhere, but don't have electronic access to it.

Your argument for completeness is correct. It is the standard one every time a topology on functions is defined by pointwise convergence in some other topology.

Comment: thank you! I missed Lemma 2.2. first..